# MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE LINES TERMINATED BY not working

Tags: mysql

I have data load from text file, looks like ID column is not coming from text file , it is coming as 0.

[image]

```
drop table table1;
create table table1 (id int, name varchar(50),Ref_by varchar(50),Dept varchar(50), city varchar (100));
select * from table1;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'G:/MYSQL_Load/Data_txt_files/db/tbl_Student.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '|||';
select * from table1;
```

After load.

[image]

Here is the sample, between Id 9 and 10 there are three lines are added as zero. I guess this is because of characters length in the text file I have 4000+ characters for one of the filed. I tired txt and csv both are getting broken.

[image]

Comment: Your lines seems to be terminated with `'|||\r\n'`. For current statement the 2nd line looks not like `2|B|...` but like `\r\n2|B|...`, and the former value is set to 0 because this cannot be treated as numeric value.

Comment: From the other side you may specify `.. LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` and use LOAD DATA IGNORE. In this case trailing `'|||'` will be treated as extra data in the line, and according to IGNORE this will generate warnings - ignore them.

Comment: The reason, I have added ||| is because my source having 5000+characters and I thought of adding something at end and move to next line. If I use '\r\n' without ||| the data is breaking and cannot go for 5000+characters.

Comment: If you share other solution that would helpful

Comment: Before proposing a workaround, please answer these questions:  Can you easily get rid of the trailing "|||"?  Does the input have "\r\n" or just "\n"?  What OS are you using?  Does every row have exactly 5 columns?

Comment: Yes, I can remove the ||| and I can change to some other style if needed like $$$ any symbol. It is a windows sever. No, it is a sample of 5 columns, the original is different in terms of column and row length, single row in a column having 5000+ characters.

Comment: Does the input have "\r\n" or just "\n"?  - i am not sure on this. i have designed | this symbol for each column and at the end of row this symbol |||. This can be changed to any other symbol.

Comment: I have added the image in the original post.