# MYSQL LOAD DATA from text file more than 4000 characters

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes

I want to LOAD DATA from text file some columns in row having more than 4000 characters, which is breaking as next line. Even I if open notepad the data in there also showing as next line and having some space in some places.

Not sure, do I need to fix the text file or load data command. It is a windows server. Any suggestions pls?

Input file text: I have hidden the words, I cannot capture everything from notepad, since I did not used word warp. You can see ID ex: 9,10,11. For characters I have used longtext data type for all columns.

[image]

[image]

For more: [MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE LINES TERMINATED BY not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321188/mysql-load-data-infile-lines-terminated-by-not-working)

[image]

Link

Comment: I don't think `LOAD DATA` will break long lines unless you are loading them into, say a column that is `VARCHAR(4000)`.  Load into `TEXT` or `MEDIUMTEXT` instead.  If that does not explain it, then I need something other than an unreadable image.

Comment: Or maybe you are saying that a "column" does have "newlines" in it (like a bunch of paragraphs)?  Have you tried something other than `\n, \r\n, ||| for `LINES TERMINATED BY`?  Or maybe that is what you mean by notepad.

Comment: Sorry you are not on Linux; there is a simple sed command.

Comment: *Even I if open notepad the data in there also showing as next line and having some space in some places.* Does it only shows these linebreaks but they are not present in the file really? Try the next: create a table with autoincremented PK and one data column of LONGTEXT datatype and load your file into it, then look at the data imported - does the imported lines which are divided to a lot of rows are absent?

Comment: Thanks Akina and Rick James for the assistance.

Comment: I have uploaded the sample notepad.

Comment: @Akina I have did the test with ID and single column. The original has 6 rows and after import it comes as 24 rows with ID 0.  does the imported lines which are divided to a lot of rows are absent -- This is correct, it gets divided.

Comment: I have data in note something like below. First line is good ID with small characters and one empty line and then very long characters this is where it is getting divided. Pls see new image in the post.

Comment: *The original has 6 rows and after import it comes as 24 rows* Your experiment shows that your CSV file data is already damaged. So the importing problem is an effect of incorrect source data. You'd restore correct state of your CSV - get its correct version or edit current file.

Comment: Thank you, let me check it.